# Dynamics Crm 2016 online: client-side record creation preventing not working

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2016

I try to prevent the creation of an appointment if some conditions are satisfied, but the line `Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs().preventDefault();` does not work and the record is created. Here is the entire code, the call is synchronous:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/appointments?$select=activityid&$filter=<my filter>", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            if(results.value.length > 0)
            {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog('It is impossible to create the appointment.');
                Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else {
            alert(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be erroring out at `Xrm.Page.context.getEventArgs()`, there is no property on the page's context object for event argument.

You should pass the execution context on save and then use the execution context's event arguments to stop the save.

Form Customization:

[image]

Handler:

```
function onSave(executionContext) {
  if(results.value.length > 0)
  {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog('It is impossible to create the appointment.');
    executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
  }
}
```